# Spark: Why does my accumulator work in non-deterministic way?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My accumulator is non-deterministic. If I run the code

```
val acc0 = sc.accumulator(0L)

sc.range(0, 20000, step = 25).foreach { l => acc0 += 1 }

println(acc0.value)
```

I get every time different values. Here is my Spark configuration

```
val SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("SparkDemoApp")
    .setMaster("local[4]")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
    .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
    .set("spark.files.overwrite", "true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")

val sc = new SparkContext(SparkConf)
```

Why is that? Why result is different from time to time?

Comment: wild guess: the code is not thread safe, and `acc0 += 1` is executed multiple times in parallel

Comment: Yeap, seems it's true, because when I set workers number to `1` (`local[1]`) it works as expected.

Comment: so you could try to change `acc0` to be volatile (don't know spark so don't know the correct syntax)

Comment: It's strange, threads should not be an issue. Silly question: is it possible, that you use one instance of accumulator running your computation few times?

Comment: @mvds It does not help.

Comment: This is probably caused by rerunning tasks and counting them multiple times There is comprehensive blog post about this http://imranrashid.com/posts/Spark-Accumulators/ In short you should never be totally confident in value of counters They are only useful for aproximating real value

Comment: Very odd - I couldn't reproduce the issue, using your code I only get the correct result (800). Which Spark version are you using? (I'm on 1.5.2)

Comment: My version is 1.6.0.